# 'List other names used' section on US Passport Renewal form too small for full name?

Tags: usa, passports

Renewing a passport after a married name change, and the section that asks for other names used is only 17 characters long.

Even a common name like 'Jonathan Perry Smith' has 20 characters.

What do you put there? Just then different last name?

Comment: Which "US Passport Renewal Form" are you using?

Comment: "Attach additional pages if needed", or use https://pptform.state.gov/

Comment: @xngtng that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica as far as I'm aware there's only one such form, the DS-82 ("US Passport Renewal Application for Eligible Individuals"), but in any event form DS-11 ("Application for a US Passport") also has two fields of 17 characters each for the same data point, so the problem is the same with both forms, as is, presumably, the solution.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I wanted to look at the form, but was too lazy to look it up. I suspected that there was likely an "attach additional pages" option or "add extra information" box, as xngtng has commented.

Answer (score 6):

As the instruction says, you may attach additional pages if needed. You can put something like "SEE ANNEX/ATTACHED/ADDTL PAGE" in the main form and attach a separate sheet for the full name(s).

You can also use the formfiller available at https://pptform.state.gov/, which generates a filled printable form and allows names longer than 17 characters. But note that you should not make any handwritten corrections to the electronically generated forms, and technically problems may happen for some browsers.